# SMTP email doesnt send

Tags: php, smtp

I'm trying to send an email via smtp, but unfortunately, it is not being sent. There seems to be no errors. Where do I have a mistake?

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                   // send via SMTP
$mail->Host     = "mail.site.org"; // SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "info@site.org";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "123456"; // SMTP password

$mail->From     = "info@bosiadbodrum.org"; // smtp kullanıcı adınız ile aynı olmalı
$mail->Fromname = "giden ismi";
$mail->AddAddress("info@alanadi.com","Ornek Isim");
$mail->Subject  =  $_POST['baslik'];
$mail->Body     =  implode("    ",$_POST);

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Mail couldnt send <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Mail sent";
```

Comment: So what's the output when you run it? Do you see the `Mail couldnt send` message or the `Mail sent` message?

Comment: Do you have an SMTP server? What is in the logs?

Comment: Yes I have Smtp Server . I checked it using  a check script on web. Problem is  After sending mail. I get " message sent" report but I got have not mail.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, to get errors:

```
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
$mail->IsSMTP();                                   // send via SMTP
$mail->Host     = "mail.site.org"; // SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "info@site.org";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "123456"; // SMTP password

$mail->From     = "info@bosiadbodrum.org"; // smtp kullanıcı adınız ile aynı olmalı
$mail->Fromname = "giden ismi";
$mail->AddAddress("info@alanadi.com","Ornek Isim");
$mail->Subject  =  $_POST['baslik'];
$mail->Body     =  implode("    ",$_POST);
$mail->Send();
echo "Message Sent OK\n";
} 
catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage();
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. After sending this one I got" message sent" report. But not mail to my my mailbox.

Comment: Anything appears in your SMTP log?